# How to select input elements with custom data atributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all selected checkboxes with a custom data attribute.

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="5">
```

`$("input[data-name='id']:selected") and $("input:selected[data-name='id']")`

don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkboxes and radio get `checked` not `selected`. Below will create an array of all the checked checkboxes.

```js
var arry = [];
$("input[data-name='id']:checked").each(function(){
 arry.push(this.value);
});

console.log(arry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input checked type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="5">
<input checked type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="3">
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it.

Answer (score 3):

The below should select based on the data-name attribute combined with :checked selector

```js
console.log($('[data-name=id]:checked'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="5"> 
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="6" checked> 
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="7"> 
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="8" checked> 
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" data-name="id" value="9" checked>
```